# Convert passive voice to active voice

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

I am writing an article for the community website. I was proofing with Grammarly before publishing. I found one sentence asking me to convert it into active voice. Now I know a bit about active and passive voice but this sentence is bit hard to convert from passive to active. Can anyone please help me to turn this into active voice?

> When community shows their love to you, it is become the
>   mutual/unsigned contract between You and Community to provide them a
>   great platform to make their life easier to maintain their photos
>   website.

I would also thankful if you can point out any other mistake is in this sentence.

Comment: The only passive construction in this sentence is "is become", which is grammatically invalid because "become" is an intransitive verb. Otherwise, every clause is already active.

Answer (score -2):

I took a stab at re-writing your sentence:

When your community shows their love to you by posting their photos on your website, it becomes your responsibility (as an implied contract) for you to provide them with a (great) platform that allows them to easily maintain and update their photos.

Note that you can remove the optional parts of the sentence above (within the parentheses) or just leave those parts in.

Comment: @MarkRipley So: the Help Center descriptions of what constitutes a useful question, the objective of the site, the reasoning which supports the policy that discourages proofreading, editing, and rewriting questions: none of this is as important to you as that 15 reputation "points". Have you read any of that material?

Comment: This does not address the fact that there is no grammatically valid passive construction in the sentence to begin with.

Comment: @StoneyB can you please help me to correct it. I would appreciate. I am not native English so I don't know the construct.

Comment: @pixelngrain *BE become* was used into the 18th century as a perfect construction, but this is not valid in present-day English: today we say "has become". In PDE *BE* is used as an auxiliary only for passive and progressive constructions. *Become* is not an *-ing* form, so this cannot be progressive; but *become* is not a transitive verb, so it cannot be cast in the passive.